# Use of collect_set(struct in Apache Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table contains 2 million fields, which is registered in Spark Dataframe.

The table is look like this:

```
CUSTADDRESSID   ADDRESSTYPE ADDRESSLINE1    ADDRESSLINE2    ADDRESSLINE3    CITY    STATE   COUNTRY ZIP1    ISACTIVE    ISCOMMUNICATION CREATEDDATE CREATEDUSER UPDATEDDATE UPDATEDUSER REASONCODE  ZIP2    C_ACCNO CUSTOMERID  ACCOUNTGROUPID  PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID  PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE    SOURCEOFENTRY   REVENUECATEGORYID   VEHICLENUMBER   VEHICLECLASS    SERIALNO    HEXTAGID    TAGSTATUS   TAGSTARTEFFDATE TAGENDEFFDATE   ISTAGBLACKLISTED    ISBLACKLISTHOLD RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS    EMAILADDRESS    PHONENUMBER CCreatedDate    CCreatedUser    CUpdatedDate    CUpdatedUser    HISTID  ACTION  ISFEEWAIVER FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE   VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS    TAGTID  ISREVENUERECHARGE   RowNumber
41  Mailing B309 PROGRESSIVE SIGNATURE  SECTOR-6    GHANSOLI    NAVI MUMBAI MH  IND 400701  1   1   2013-06-07 12:55:54.827 bhagwadapos 2013-06-07 12:55:54.827 bhagwadapos NULL    NULL    10003014    20000001    15  3079    2015-09-16 14:58:27.500 RegularRetailer 75  MH43AJ411   4   206158433290    91890704803000000C0A    TAGINACTIVE 2014-08-08 14:24:12.227 2039-08-08 23:59:59.000 1   0   NULL    shankarn75@rediffmail.com                                                                                                                               9004419178      2013-06-07 12:56:16.650 bhagwadapos 2015-09-16 14:58:33.190 BatchProcess    15250   UPDATE  NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    1
```

I want to transform into JSON and the JSON file should be look like this probably, sorry I have designed manually in hand:

```
ACCOUNTNO    :    10003018
ADDRESS      :    Array
                0    :    Object
VEHICLE    :    Array
                0    :    Object
```

I have written the Spark SQL query but I am unable to create two arrays `VEHICLE` & `ADDRESS` under `ACCOUNTNO`

So this is the query:

```
val query2 = "SELECT C_ACCNO AS ACCOUNTNO, collect_set(struct(VEHICLENUMBER, CUSTOMERID,ACCOUNTGROUPID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSID,PREPAIDACCOUNTSTATUSDATE,SOURCEOFENTRY,REVENUECATEGORYID,VEHICLECLASS,SERIALNO,HEXTAGID,TAGSTATUS,TAGSTARTEFFDATE,TAGENDEFFDATE,ISTAGBLACKLISTED,ISBLACKLISTHOLD,RCVERIFICATIONSTATUS,EMAILADDRESS,PHONENUMBER,CREATEDDATE,CREATEDUSER,UPDATEDDATE,UPDATEDUSER,ISFEEWAIVER,FEEWAIVERPASSTYPE,VEHICLEIMGVERIFICATIONSTATUS,TAGTID,ISREVENUERECHARGE)) as VEHICLE FROM joined_acc_add GROUP BY ACCOUNTNO ORDER BY ACCOUNTNO"
```

and there after:

```
val res01 = sqlContext.sql(query2.toString)
res01.coalesce(1).write.json("D:/result01")
```

I need help to find my mistake in the Query. This query is throwing error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done. The query to create multiple arrays under one object should be like this.

```
val query1 = "SELECT PKcolumn1, collect_set(struct(column2, column3)), collect_set(struct(column4, column5)), collect_set(struct(column6, column7)) GROUP BY PKcolumn1 ORDER BY PKcolumn1"
```